# Dataframe filter with multi-index: return all rows at top index level given value filters

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm looking for the syntax to return all first tier data given multiple end value criteria.  I've been reading and finding filtering solutions with .loc or .xs but I can quite get the syntax for what I want.
I use to work with xpath and I just want `//A[ B [ @x=1 and @y=2]]` in essence.

I've tried lots of permutations of syntax I'm familiar with using forms of df.loc df.xs mutlti [], a little with df.index.get_level_values(), etc...

So from a dataframe like this:

             `x      y
A    B
a    b      1      2 
a    f      4      5
a    c      3      4 
b    d      1      5

b    c      1      2 
c    d      2      3`

I want to search for a specific combo of x and y and return all rows at the A index level.

So I want x=1 and y=2 and get

`x      y 
A    B 
a    b      1      2 
a    f      4      5
a    c      3      4 
b    d      1      5 
b    c      1      2`

Because at least 1 single row of a given A matches

And even better more general solution would be to search for an x value of a particular B and y value of a particular different B.

(trying for more clarity): By this I mean, instead of end level values I'm looking for, I may be interested in combination only specific B values.
Below I have B<sub>1</sub>= b and x=3.  so I'm mixing matching a value with matching an index value.  Whereas before I limited two end values.  Again, I envision this in xpath like  `//A[ B [ local-name() == b and @x=3] and B[ local-name() == f and @y=5] ]`  (I think I got that right).

For example, B<sub>1</sub>=b: x=3 and B<sub>2</sub>=f: y=5 . Returning:

`x      y 
A    B 
a    b      1      2 
a    f      4      5
a    c      3      4`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you state the second part of your problem more clearly? Do all conditions have to be met, and in what combination? Or are you still filtering by `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on level = 'A' and [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) after creating a `flag` column for each `x` and `y` columns if the values you are looking for are in it with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
#using @jpp setup
import numpy as np
df['flagx'] = np.where(df.x == 1,1,0)
df['flagy'] = np.where(df.y == 5,1,0)
```

Now, if you want that both `x` and `y` meet the condition for any value of `B` and the same `A`, you can use `any` on each flag and look for both with `&`:

```
print (df.groupby(level='A').filter(lambda dfg: dfg.flagx.any() & dfg.flagy.any() )
         .drop(['flagx','flagy'],axis=1))
     x  y
A B      
a b  1  2
  f  4  5
  c  3  4
b d  1  5
  c  1  2
```

If you want that both conditions on `x` and `y` are met on the same row, then you can do it by changing the position of the `any` and the `&` in the `filter`:

```
print (df.groupby(level='A').filter(lambda dfg: (dfg.flagx & dfg.flagy).any() )
         .drop(['flagx','flagy'],axis=1))
     x  y
A B      
b d  1  5
  c  1  2
```

Comment: Happy new year  to you :-)

Comment: @W-B you too, and a lot of answer on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work.  It also allowed me to handle an index with a space in it pretty easily. Thanks! Happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

You can [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) your dataframe via a couple of steps:

```
A_idx = df.query('x == 1 & y == 2').index.get_level_values('A')
res = df.query('A in @A_idx')

print(res)

#      x  y
# A B      
# a b  1  2
#   f  4  5
#   c  3  4
# b d  1  5
#   c  1  2
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 1, 2], ['a', 'f', 4, 5], ['a', 'c', 3, 4],
                   ['b', 'd', 1, 5], ['b', 'c', 1, 2], ['c', 'd', 2, 3]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'x', 'y'])

df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: Happy new year :-)

Comment: This worked great for that example data set.  Is it possible to tweak to accommodate an index with a space... "A 2" instead of "A" for example? reading around quickly it seems spaces and query don't get along.  Thanks (and happy new year!)

Comment: @DontJudgeMyADD, You can always use `loc`, e.g. replace `df.query('x == 1 & y == 2')` with `df.loc[df['x'].eq(1) & df['y'].eq(2))`. And happy new year!

Comment: @W-B, happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby`+`transform`+`any`

```
df[df.eq({'x':1,'y':2}).groupby(level=0).transform('any').any(1)]
     x  y
A B      
a b  1  2
  f  4  5
  c  3  4
b d  1  5
  c  1  2
```

Comment: Nice for the method `eq` with both columns in a `dict` :-)

Comment: Hi! that returns a blank table for me.  I'm missing the dict setup, right? Thanks

Comment: @DontJudgeMyADD {'x':1,'y':2} this is the dict I use . and work fine on my side

Comment: Thanks @W-B, I'm not sure why it's not working for me.  I copy pasted it directly and cannot get .eq() to take more than one entry like you have.  I've been search for quite a while and can't find a good tutorial on using .eq like that either.